# Error while running make in Hyperledger Fabric on MacOS

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have installed all the prerequisites for Fabric.

- OS: Mac OS X EI Capitan
- Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
- docker-compose version 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b
- go version go1.10.3 darwin/amd64
- GOPATH="/usr/local/go"
- GOROOT="/usr/local/go"

I have placed the Fabric in `/usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric` and added GOPATH in the PATH variable of the system.

While running the `make docker` command, I get the following error:

```
Building .build/docker/bin/peer
can't load package: package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer" in any of:
    /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer (from $GOROOT)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer (from $GOPATH)

make: *** [.build/docker/bin/peer] Error 1
```

I also went through the Makefile rule for the same:

```
# We (re)build a package within a docker context but persist the $GOPATH/pkg
# directory so that subsequent builds are faster
$(BUILD_DIR)/docker/bin/%: $(PROJECT_FILES)
        $(eval TARGET = ${patsubst $(BUILD_DIR)/docker/bin/%,%,${@}})
        @echo "Building $@"
        @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)/docker/bin $(BUILD_DIR)/docker/$(TARGET)/pkg
        @$(DRUN) \
                -v $(abspath $(BUILD_DIR)/docker/bin):/opt/gopath/bin \
                -v $(abspath $(BUILD_DIR)/docker/$(TARGET)/pkg):/opt/gopath/pkg \
                $(BASE_DOCKER_NS)/fabric-baseimage:$(BASE_DOCKER_TAG) \
                go install -tags "$(GO_TAGS)" -ldflags "$(DOCKER_GO_LDFLAGS)" $(pkgmap.$(@F))
        @touch $@
```

The error seems to be the with the line `$(BASE_DOCKER_NS)/fabric-baseimage:$(BASE_DOCKER_TAG) \`. I tried to replace $(BASE_DOCKER_NS) with absolute path, i.e. `/usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger`. It again gives the error:

> docker: invalid reference format.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that Is `/usr/local/go` is not shared with Docker.  Assuming you are using Docker for Mac, you can check this by right-clicking on the Docker icon in the status bar and selecting `Preferences` and then the `File Sharing` tab.  You will need to add `/usr/local/go`  if it's not in the list.  If you are using Docker Toolbox, you'll need to add shared folders via the [VirtualBox GUI](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_mac/#optional-add-shared-directories).

If you run `make docker` for Fabric 1.4 and earlier, it there's multiple stages to the build. The first stage involves building the binaries in a Docker container and mounts the current directory as a volume.  This is the error you are getting since the host path is not shared with Docker.

If you run `make docker` on the master branch, you won't run into this issue as master uses multi-stage Docker builds instead.

Comment: Seems plausible explanation. But I did not find any Preference option to add `/usr/local/go

Comment: OK ... you'll need to look at https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_mac/#optional-add-shared-directories.  Also amended answer above with this info

Comment: You need to make sure the `Name` and `Path` are both set to `/usr/local/go`.  By default, VB likes to shorten the name to the last part off the path; you'll need to manually change it

Comment: I tried that too, saved the settings, but the same error persists :/